# Ubuntu boot partition size problem

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, lvm

I have this constant problem with Ubuntu boot partition size, however I can't resize the other partition because it's an LVM encrypted partition.

1. Resize the ext4 boot partition to give some 200-300MB to the fat32 boot partition.
2. Reinstall all the system with Timeshift to recover all my data and have a bigger boot.
3. Move boot in another hard drive.

   My actual hard drive:

   [image: my actual hard drive]

I've been stuck with this problem for months. I was able to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 after deleting all the kernels, but now I can't even perform an update/upgrade because of insufficient disk space.

Comment: 732mb for the `/boot` partition should be plenty of space. Have you tried removing old kernels with `sudo apt autoremove`?

Comment: the fat32 boot partition is the problem not the ext4 and yes i tried it all remove all kernels etc

Comment: My  dual boot Win/Ubuntu efi partition is less than 37MB, so your 500MB should be plenty. What exact error messages do you get?

Comment: I re-installed ubuntu and now is fine!